# Python 2 - Summing numbers in a list

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to do a practice problem that involves summing numbers in a loop. I thought the following code would work but I my answer was wrong. Any ideas??

```
sortedList = map(int, "283 889 22 352 744 969 40 1248 309 197 1274 630 1040 1161 1040 338 486 295 202 914 778 428 405 483 662 363 1139 968 943 820 481 1217 408 493 268 1143 161 299 1090 461 486 1064 1081".split())

sum = 0
for number in sortedList:
    sum += sortedList.pop

print sum
```

Comment: Switch to `while sortedList:` (although it *isn't* sorted) or `sum += number` or just use `sum`. **Don't** change the length of lists while you `for` loop over them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code gives an error, you forgot the parenthesis for the function `pop`:

```
for number in sortedList:
    sum += sortedList.pop()
```

Note that you also could have used the function `sum`:

```
sum(sortedList)
```

but since you used the variable `sum`, this function could not be used.

**Edit 1**: like commented by jonrsharpe, your method is in fact wrong! You are going through the list with `for`, but at the same time you are popping (i.e. getting and removing the last item), this is why your answer is wrong: 14866 instead of 28074.

You can either use the `sum` function I mentioned or do:

```
s = 0
for number in sortedList:
    s += number
```

or with pop:

```
s = 0
while sortedList:
    s += sortedList.pop()
```

Comment: Won't this still fail when it tries to iterate over the list as it shortens?